# Density of $C([0,T];V)$ in $L^2((0,T);H)$ for $V$ dense in $H$ (Bochner spaces and continuous functions)

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, lp-spaces, approximation, bochner-spaces

I'm trying to find a good reference for the claim from the caption. In my case, I have $V = H_0^1(\Omega)$ and $H = L^2(\Omega)$. I already know (or am pretty sure) that $C([0,T];V)$ is dense in $L^2((0,T);V)$ (since a similar result holds in usual Lp spaces) and that $L^2((0,T);V)$ is dense in $L^2((0,T);H)$ but I don't really have any reference for that.

I'm actually not discussing Bochner spaces in detail in my thesis but still need this result, i.e. a good reference for it.
Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The assertion in the title doesn't always hold, though it may hod in the cases  you care about. Take $V=\mathbb Q$ and $H=\mathbb R$. Then $C([0,T],V)$ contains only constant functions, so it's not dense in $L^2((0,T),H)$.